# Determining solubility of a gas in a molten salt

Tags: solubility, gas-laws

If pressure and temperature are known constants, how can I determine the solubility of a known amount of gas in a mixture of molten salts?

Assume the mixture of salts is homogeneous and the composition (as well as amount of said compounds) is known.

Comment: Long story short, you can't.

Comment: Arbitrary gas and salt mixture? Why even think there's non-negligable solubility?

Comment: @IvanNeretin of course it is possible. Geologists and volcanologists have spent decades experimentally measuring the solubility of various gases in various molten liquids (some of which are not too different from molten salts).

Comment: @Mithoron once you increase pressure above atmospheric, you can dissolve pretty much any gas in any liquid.

Comment: Pumice illustrates this solubility of gases in lava.

Comment: All right, "determine" is an awfully broad term. Can you calculate it with a few simple rules? No. Can you measure it experimentally? Sure, why not.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the phase diagram of the gas, and can calculate the exact pressure the gas should have given the volume outside of the molten salt, you can use the measured pressure/temperature to determine any difference in pressure. Then you can calculate the number of moles of gas that must be absorbed to generate the pressure difference. 
If the gas is relatively inert (which it probably needs to be if it wont react with molten salt), you can probably use the ideal gas equation:
$$P_0V = NRT$$
If you compare to the actual pressure, you can determine the number of moles absorbed by the salt:
$$\delta N = (P_0-P_\mathrm{exp})V/(RT)$$

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The solubility does not depend (at least directly) on volumes. The solubility can be parameterised experimentally for any liquid-has pair, and then calculated using that.

Comment: I don't think you understood why I used the ideal gas law here. The solubility is directly related to how much gas is absorbed at a specific pressure/temperature. You can use the ideal gas law to calculate an estimate on how much gas has been absorbed by the molten salt. If the amount of salt is known, then the solubility can be calculated trivially.

Comment: _"You can use the ideal gas law to calculate an estimate on how much gas has been absorbed by the molten salt."_ - No, you cannot.

Comment: Can you explain your logic? Why would a pressure loss not be due to absorbance? It is not helpful to simply say "you're wrong".

Comment: Because once you're a bit higher than atmospheric pressure, things do not act as ideal gases any more. For example, oxygen fugacity can be an order of magnitude higher than oxygen partial pressure. As solubility is determined by fugacity, not partial pressure. Furthermore, the composition of the molten salt has a very strong influence on the solubility of gases in it. Furthermore, at temperatures high enough to melt salts, you will get salt vapour as well and your atmosphere is not the pure gas any more. And let's remember that you have an unknown molar volume of the gas component in the salt.

Comment: As temperature increases, intermolecular attractive forces decrease as the kinetic terms dominate. If you look at the van der Waals equation of state, a high temperature (or low pressure) results in behavior that is approximately equal to an ideal gas. You are correct about salt vapor pressure coming into play, however it is negligible. NaCl for example has pressure <100kPa at 1700K (well beyond the melting point). One can know how many moles are in the salt using experimental data for the gas P-T (or equation of state if data unavailable) and finding the difference between vapor pressure.

Comment: The salt vapour pressure is negligible compared to what? To the solubility of gases in the salt melt? It is also going to be negligible at high temperature. So you are comparing one negligible thing to another. And let's not forget that salt melts are extremely corrosive and will react with the container to some degree, leading to another source of uncertainty. Doing this kind of stuff is literally my job. If you find a way to do it according to your method, let me know. We probably have a _Nature Geoscience_ or _Nature Chemistry_ paper here.

Comment: Of course my suggestion isn't supposed to be perfectly accurate, but according to this chem rev paper, solubility of several gasses in molten salts obey Henry's law: https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/cr60242a003 
The proportionality constants may be determined from existing data to get an estimation.

Comment: Noble gas solubilities in molten salts in atmospheric pressures are irrelevant. OP specifically asked for pressure to be a variable, and this will deviate strongly from ideal behaviour once you have things that are not noble gases.